# measuring code coverage of an unit test using aqtime

Tags: c++, boost, code-coverage, aqtime

I want to measure the code coverage of an unit test with aqtime. The application to test uses a lot of boost functionality. Now these boost methods appear in the test report. With these methods in the report, it is nearly impossible to interpret it since I did not test boost but the classes using boost.

Is there a fast way to exclude boost from the code coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

- run with everything
- create a filter that includes
  everything you don't want
- select all elements of the filter
- create an excluding area for all
  those elements
- run again and refine.